# Formatting date in specified timezone using Moment Timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, dst

If you change time zone to (UTC-07:00) Mountain Time and run the code below you can see the problem that I'm talking about.

```js
var a = moment('2009-11-01T06:00:00Z').tz('US/Mountain').format();
var b = moment('2009-11-01T06:00:00Z').tz('US/Mountain').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
var c = moment('2009-10-31T23:00:00-07:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');

document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "#1: " + a;
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "#2: " + b;
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = "#3: " + c;
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

The date offset produced by running the code (#1) above is correct. However, shouldn't formatting it change the value to "2009-11-01 00:00" (#3) instead of "2009-10-31 23:00" (#2)?

It seems like the formatter just strips the offset instead of taking it into account when producing the formatted date. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Presumably by Mountain Time you mean GMT-07:00. While parsing of strings by the Date constructor is not recommended, most will parse that string correctly (but some wont). Anyway, it seems your system is set to GMT-06:00, so when you print the date the default is to use the local (host system) time zone, which is one hour later than input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js` with year 2009. You should change Moment Timezone to `moment-timezone-with-data.min.js`. See working code snippet:

```js
var a = moment('2009-11-01T06:00:00Z').tz('US/Mountain').format();
var b = moment('2009-11-01T06:00:00Z').tz('US/Mountain').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
var c = moment('2009-10-31T23:00:00-07:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');

document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "#1: " + a;
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "#2: " + b;
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = "#3: " + c;
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```